# Can anyone explain what this line in shell script does?

Tags: sed

`sed -i.bak "/"string"/s/$/ "num"/" filename`

Where "string" is a pattern, "num" is a number and "filename" is a name of file

Comment: Have you considered just trying it?

Comment: @tink Actually I did, I need someone to explain what eveything on the command does. Not what is the result if this command, or its function.

Comment: This page (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains sed very well and also it has a
fantastic set of other unix tutorials
(https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` reads lines one at a time and applies the script's actions to each in turn.

The `-i.bak` option says to write changes back to the original file name, and save the previous contents with a `.bak` extension.

The script adds `num` with a space before it to lines which contain `string` somewhere within them.

The shell quoting is basically broken; the author seems to have been guessing where the quotes are necessary. But the only crucial quoting here is that the space before `num` needs to be inside quotes, which happened to succeed. With less haphazard quoting, the script could be written

```
sed -i.bak '/string/s/$/ num/' filename
```

The general syntax of a `sed` script is a sequence of `<address>`, `<action>` pairs, where `<address>` is optional; if it is missing, the `<action>` is applied to all lines. But here, the `<address>` selects only lines which match the regex between the first pair of slashes, and the `<action>` is the `s` substitution command. The regex `$` matches the position just before the end of each line, and the replacement is just a static string.